# Messy string column to wide format

Tags: r, string, dplyr, reshape

I have the following data set:

### Input

```
date        string                                           value
2021-01-01  a=uk_b=goo1_c=brandA_d=phrase_d1 for pedro 2020    20
2021-02-01  a=us_b=goo2_c=brandB_d=phrase_d2 for peter 2020    30
2021-01-15  a=ca_b=goo2_c=brandC_e=102331                      40
2022-01-15  2                                                   0
```

I need to create a wide data frame based on values in `string` (see output below).I have hundreds of names, this is just a reproducible example.

### Desired output

```
date        a   b     c      d                          e     value 2
2021-01-01  uk  goo1  brandA phrase_d1 for pedro 2020   NA     20  NA
2021-02-01  us  goo2  brandB phrase_d2 for peter 2020   NA     30  NA
2021-01-15  ca  goo2  brandC NA                        102331  40  NA
2022-01-15  NA  NA    NA     NA                         NA      0  NA
```

What would be a neat solution? I'm thinking of a combination of reshape and sub probably will take care of it.

### Data

```
data = data.frame(date =c("2021-01-01","2021-02-01","2021-01-15","2022-01-15"),
                  string = c("a=uk_b=goo1_c=brandA_d=phrase_d1 for pedro 2020",
                             "a=us_b=goo2_c=brandB_d=phrase_d2 for peter 2020",
                             "a=ca_b=goo2_c=brandC_e=102331",2),
                  value = c(20,30,40,0))
```

Comment: Split on `=` and `_` would be a good start. What have you tried?

Comment: You could look into `tidyr::separate()` as well

Comment: @zx8754 The challange is having both! So I won't get what I want using normal strsplit.

Comment: @jpsmith that actually gave me an idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaulS's solution is more succinct than mine, but requires that the only underscores in the strings that are to be printed in the variables have a `d` and then a number behind them.  If there are underscores that have other unknown patterns following them, the solution will break.  Here's a quick example:

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date,        ~string,                                           ~value,
"2021-01-01",  "abc=uk_def=goo1_ghi=brandA_jkl=phrase_dx for pedro 2020", 20,
"2021-02-01",  "abc=us_def=goo2_ghi=brandB_jkl=phrase_d2 for peter 2020", 30,
"2021-01-015", "abc=ca_def=goo2_ghi=brandC_mno=102331", 40)

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)


dat %>% 
  separate_rows(string, sep="_(?!d\\d)") %>% 
  separate(string, into=c("n1", "n2"), sep = "=", fill = "right") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(date, value), names_from = n1, values_from = n2)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   date        value abc   def   ghi    jkl                `dx for pedro …` mno  
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <chr>            <chr>
#> 1 2021-01-01     20 uk    goo1  brandA phrase             <NA>             <NA> 
#> 2 2021-02-01     30 us    goo2  brandB phrase_d2 for pet… <NA>             <NA> 
#> 3 2021-01-015    40 ca    goo2  brandC <NA>               <NA>             1023…
```

My solution is a bit more complicated, but I think it works in a wider variety of cases:

```r
make_df <- function(string){
  str <- str_split(string, "=", simplify=TRUE)
  if(length(str) == 1){
    nm <- str[1]
    str <- list(NA)
    names(str) <- nm 
  }
  if(length(str) > 1){
    nm <- c(str[1], gsub(".*_(.*?)$", "\\1", str[2:(length(str)-1)]))
    str <- str[-1]
    str <- gsub(paste0("_", nm, collapse="|"), "", str)
    str <- as.list(str)
    names(str) <- nm
  }
  do.call(data.frame, str)
}

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(out = make_df(string)) %>% 
  unnest(out) %>% 
  select(-string)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   date        value abc   def   ghi    jkl                      mno    X2   
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>                    <chr>  <lgl>
#> 1 2021-01-01     20 uk    goo1  brandA phrase_dx for pedro 2020 <NA>   NA   
#> 2 2021-02-01     30 us    goo2  brandB phrase_d2 for peter 2020 <NA>   NA   
#> 3 2021-01-015    40 ca    goo2  brandC <NA>                     102331 NA   
#> 4 2021-91-15      0 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>                     <NA>   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If the strings with underscores in them are as regular as in the example, the @PaulS's solution is better.  Otherwise, this one might work.

Comment: The challange is I just simplified the question for better understanding. In the actual data I have more character  instead of a,b,c,d. it's about 200 variation of alphabet like "tr" and "vt".

Comment: The example above will deal with those, in the example above, I used "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" and "mno" as variable names instead of a,b,c,d,e.  It will detect the name between the closest previous underscore to the equal sign.

Comment: You are correct! made some adjustments, almost made it work. Now the challange is when I only have 1 word in the string! like "Poland". I tried to fix it by changing them to "tr=poland" or "_tr=poland" but neither will solve the problem with names(str) <- nm.

Comment: Can you update the question with an example that doesn't work and we can troubleshoot together from there?

Comment: I have updated the question. Also solved the problem by changing the data using a case_when: !grepl("_",string) ~ paste0("num=",string,"_test=NULL"). I would appreciate a neater solution of course!

Comment: I updated the `make_df()` function so that if the splitting produces only one value, that value becomes the name of a new variable that is missing for all observations.  In this case, since the single value is 2 and R won't produce data frames with variable names that are numbers, it prints the name as `X2`.

Comment: Perfect! may I ask what is the use of , labs=letters[1:5] in the function arguments?

Comment: The `labs` argument allows you to identify the names of the variables, though it shouldn't be there, it doesn't do anything in particular in this version of the function.  I'll edit the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(string, sep="_(?!d\\d)") %>% 
  separate(string, into=c("n1", "n2"), sep = "=", fill = "right") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(date, value), names_from = n1, values_from = n2)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   date       value a     b     c      d                        e     
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>                    <chr> 
#> 1 2021-01-01    20 uk    goo1  brandA phrase_d1 for pedro 2020 <NA>  
#> 2 2021-02-01    30 us    goo2  brandB phrase_d2 for peter 2020 <NA>  
#> 3 2021-01-15    40 ca    goo2  brandC <NA>                     102331
```